# Under Trinity Desktop, How do I get kdDebug output from KHTMLPart in my own application?

Tags: debugging, kde-plasma

I've got an application written using the current Trinity Desktop (KDE3.5 or thereabouts) (platform is CentOS 7, x86_64). Something we're doing is causing bad behavior out of KHTMLPart, and I'm trying to understand what's going wrong, and I'd like to get the debug outputs from KHTMLPart.

Looking at the KDE 3.5 sources, I see that such messages should have an id of 6050, and so I looked at /opt/trinity/share/config/kdebugrc. I tried adding this block:

```
[6050]
InfoOutput=0
WarnOutput=0
ErrorOutput=0
FatalOutput=0
```

to that file with no effect. I also tried in ~/.trinity/share/config/kdebugrc, also with no effect.

Should kdebugrc changes work when the app is my own? Am I putting this block in the right place? Is there something I need to do in my KApplication to make this work?

I expected that messages would show in /var/log/dbg.log.

I also tried making everything =2 and =3 to try to get messages on syslog and stdout respectively, with no luck on either, leading me to the inescapable conclusion that I'm doing something very wrong.

Comment: Did you specify the file somewhere?
I.e. do you have lines like `InfoFilename=/var/log/dbg.log` for that debug area code in another kdebugrc file or below the part you've posted?
By default the file logging goes to a file called `kdebug.dbg` in the startup directory of the application

Comment: @KevinKrammer - no, I didn't specify the file - I was looking for kdebug.dbg and don't see it anywhere. I also tried setting it to do syslog or stdout debugging, neither of which worked either, which is why I suspect that I've done something else wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I've only ever used "stdout" logging and that either went to the shell when the program was launched manually from there or to $HOME/.xsession-errors when launched via the desktop.
KDE3 actual though, not TDE